# Change Textview's color on click

Tags: colors, textview, android

I would like to change the color of my textview when it is clicked.

Actually, I have this xml code.

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:autoLink="web"
    android:duplicateParentState="true"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button_modif"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button_modif"
    android:text="Informations personnelles:"
    android:textColor="#00A9A9"
    android:textSize="7pt"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
```

How can I achieve my goal?

Thanks in advance

Regards

Answer (score 0):

What do you want to change? The color of the text inside it or the background color of the textview?

If you want to change the color of the background, you can use this,

```
    tv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            tv.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        }
    });
```

But if you want to change its text color, use this,

```
tv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            tv.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        }
    });
```

I hope it helps.